# How to make a mobile or web app to call to landline or cell phone number

Tags: webrtc, twilio, asterisk, sip, voip

I am going to make a mobile&web app and backend system to setup a call to landline phone number or cell phone number. Like whatsapp or hangout.

I have investigated the paid services such as Twilio, OnSIP, Linphone, etc, but I'm not sure which one I can use and how I should use.

To do this, what kind of services could be there and how to make the app with them? Also, is there any demo service or opensource to make a call to landline or cell phone as a test?

Comment: WebRTC seems like a good path to go if you need browser based phone calls.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not expert in voip, it is really unlikly you can do anything "like whatsapp" and that system will work correctly.

Call from softphones to sip provider - check sip solutions, asterisk(simple&low volume), kamailio/opensips(complex but very  high load supported).

For call from webpage check WebRTC project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I setup Asterisk or Kamilio SIP environment you mentioned, could I make a call to landline or cell phone without a partnership with the telecom carrier? I would like to know the entire system architecture to implement such call. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't pay PAYED network without use of PAYED provider. Except variant when you do your own PSTN network and connect it via e1/pstn or fxo gates.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not correct site to teach you base of telephony. Read book or wikipedia.

Comment: I see and I will investigate more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi, Wiktor Kostus, i can see that its been 6 year, do you later found a solution? if yes, may i know how you were able to do it. thanks